# Failing to update a state which is an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react state which stores:

```
permissionValue:  [{user_id: 1, landing: true, skadi: true, heimdall: true, register: true, …}]
```

And I want to update that state. So I do

```
handleChangePermissions = evt => {
  console.log(this.state.permissionValue); //I can see the initial state
  console.log("id: " + evt.target.id); //Thats the proper key
  console.log("checked: " + evt.target.checked); //Thats the proper value

  var data = this.state.permissionValue[0]; //I store the content of the array in data
  console.log("data1");
  console.log(data); //I can see the array data
  data.evt.target.id = evt.target.checked; //I set the data , supposedly, but I receive " Cannot read property 'target' of undefined "
  //Crashes
  console.log("data2");
  console.log(data);
  console.log("----");
  this.setState({
    permissionValue: data
  });
};
```

But it crashes when reading `evt` during the setting of the data. What's the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved

```
handleChangePermissions = (evt) => {
    console.log(this.state.permissionValue) 
    console.log("id: " + evt.target.id) 
    var idu = evt.target.id;
    var checked = evt.target.checked
    console.log("checked: " + evt.target.checked) 

    var data = this.state.permissionValue[0]; 
    console.log("data1")
    console.log(data) 
     data[idu] = checked; 
     console.log("data2")
     console.log(data)


       this.setState({
           permissionValue: [data]
      })


}
```

Answer (score 0):

One cause might be invoking change handler using **onChange={this.handleChange()}**
. In such case,simply pass the function as a value to onChange without invoking it.

```
onChange={this.handleChange}
```

Or try passing event object like

```
onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
```

Answer (score 0):

## State is read only

Do not modify state outside of the useState hook or this.setState.

This line is a problem because of the concept, pass by reference vs pass by value.

`data.evt.target.id = evt.target.checked`

What you need to do is make a copy of the state and make the change there. then make changes.

```
this.setState({
  permissionValue: {
    ...data,
    evt: {
      ...data.evt,
      target: {
        ...data.evt.target,
        id: evt.target.checked,
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

var data = {...this.state.permissionValue[0]}